# Linux - dtb - RAM address and size passing via dtb to kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, ram, boot, device-tree

I'm a newbie to Linux
So While booting linux on my "*cutom embedded development board*" I can see some log

```
Memory: 405860K/509952K available (2604K kernel code, 188K rwdata, 1068K rodata, 164K init, 131K bss, 87708K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved)
176 Virtual kernel memory layout:
```

Which means Linux has detected 512MB of RAM,(Eventhough I have 2GB of RAM)

I assume this infomation needs to be passed dtb, can someone help me regarding how this information node looks like and how can I increase the size of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the memory node, so that the linux can see the 2gb. you can refer this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/memory.txt). Also you might want to set CONFIG_VMSPLIT_2G